# Pinescript Arrays- multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, neural-network, pine-script

I am creating a neural net in Pine script which has two input neurons but I am having trouble creating a properly structured training data array. The net expects a two dimensional array. I am using the inbuilt neuralnetwork functions of Pine Script which I have been able to find some limited documentation for. I know how to define the weights array, declare the neural network function defining the netwrok structure and how to train the network but I need to get the training data into the correct format.

The structure of the trainingData should contain two series (say for the sake of argument they are close prices and volume for the time series). I am not concerned at this point about data standardization or normalisation as I will deal with those issues once I work out how to create the correct data array structure. Is it possible to create an array with something like this structure? This code was suggested to me by someone but it doesn't work and throws errors. I'm sure its way off beam. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I haven't used arrays much yet in Pine Script - I've used them in other types of scripting but I cant work out how to declare a two dimensional array that will do this.

```
trainingData = (0)
for i = 0 to bar_index-1
    inputData = [closePrices[i], volumes[i]]
    outputData = [closePrices[i+1], volumes[i+1]]
    trainingData.push([inputData, outputData])
```

See previous description and code. (Edit: Please not that the structure currently refers to two outputs price and volume but in reality of course Im not interested in predicting volume so there will likely only be one output neuron. )

Edit in response to the answer given. I had thought that the problem was solved but it isn't. The code still isnt compiling  without error. The following is the full code for my training function:

trainNN() =>

```
trainingData = []
for i = 0 to bar_index-1
inputData = [closePrices[i], volumes[i]]
outputData = [closePrices[i+1]]
trainingData.append([inputData, outputData])
```

The error "syntax error at '['" is thrown on compiling.and the compiler indicates the problem is at the [ in the trainingData array decalaration.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't have an `array` as elements of another `array` and create a 2D array, you can use `matrix` to "stack up" multiple arrays. You can set the return of your function as a new `row` that has `column` of the all the results you got:

```
a = array.from(close, volume)

m = matrix.new<float>()
matrix.add_row(m, matrix.rows(m), a)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(matrix.get(m, matrix.rows(m) - 1, 0)))
```

If the return type of the function you are using is a `tuple` you'll need one more step to convert the result from a `tuple` to an `array`:

```
foo() => 
    [close, volume]

[_close, _volume] = foo()

a = array.from(_close, _volume)

m = matrix.new<float>()
matrix.add_row(m, matrix.rows(m), a)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(matrix.get(m, matrix.rows(m) - 1, 0)))
```

Comment: Well I need to wrap my head around that a bit. I haven't used matrices within PS.  Why is there a str.tostring in there? Is that some sort of data type conversion? Whats that for? I don't understand how converting teh data to strings helps?

Comment: The last section is just for debugging. I've added a label to show how you can retrieve the data back from the matrix using `matrix.get(id, row, column)`. In this specific case, the `matrix.get()` function returns a `float`, and I wanted to use a label which takes a `string` as one of the parameters, so I've converted it to `string` using `str.tostring()` function